# Persist screen resolution for Server 13.04

Tags: server, resolution

I'd like to increase the screen resolution on a fresh 13.04 Server install.

I can set `nomodeset vga=791` after pressing `e` during the grub bootload, but I cannot find where to persist this value. I beleieve it should be set in `/etc/grub.d/00_header`, but I'm not sure where.

**Update**

Contents of `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` is

```
# List of modules that you want to include in your initramfs.
# They will be loaded at boot time in the order below.
#
# Syntax:  module_name [args ...]
#
# You must run update-initramfs(8) to effect this change.
#
# Examples:
#
# raid1
# sd_mod
uvesafb
```

Comment: See if [this post](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2zdMmPERCoIJ:blog.samat.org/2010/11/09/High-resolution-text-console-with-uvesafb-and-Debian+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=do) helps you.

Comment: I get a `cannot reserve video memory at 0xd0000000` after running `sudo modprobe uvesafb`.

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`? Also, what is the output of `grep vga /proc/cmdline` and of `grep -ir vga /etc/modprobe.d/` as the post explains?

Comment: There's no output from the two commands, as expected.  Updated case due to formatting issues.

Comment: You did install `v86d`, right? Also, are you running this commands from a tty?

Comment: Try with the info given in Hwoary's comment in this [post](http://idyllictux.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/lucidubuntu-10-04-high-resolution-plymouth-virtual-terminal-for-atinvidia-cards-with-proprietaryrestricted-driver/).

Comment: I was getting `[ 2.754361] uvesafb: probe of uvesafb.0 failed with error -5` from running `dmesg | grep uvesafb`. Turns out the video card driver was failing to load. Fixed that, and the original article worked. Do you want to post from the article so I can accept?

Comment: Already done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1

You can try using `uvesafb`. First, you must unset `vga`, if you get any output from this commands

```
$ grep vga /proc/cmdline
$ grep -ir vga /etc/modprobe.d/
```

you must edit the files which have `vga` enabled and disable it.

---

## 2

Now install it:

```
sudo apt-get install v86d
```

Create `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and add the line

```
uvesafb
```

(or just run `sudo sh -c "echo uvesafb >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules"`)

---

## 3

To check the display modes you have available, load the uvesafb module:

```
sudo modprobe uvesafb
```

and read the file `/sys/bus/platform/drivers/uvesafb/uvesafb.0/vbe_modes`.

---

## 4

To set the display mode you want, create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/uvesafb.conf` and add the line:

```
options uvesafb mode_option=1280x1024-32 scroll=ywrap
```

(change the resolution/color-depth to suit your needs, based on the available modes.)

---

## 5

Now to try it out, run

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
```

and reboot.

---

### References

1. [High-resolution text console with uvesafb and Debian](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2zdMmPERCoIJ%3ablog.samat.org/2010/11/09/High-resolution-text-console-with-uvesafb-and-Debian+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=do)
2. [[Lucid][Ubuntu 10.04] High resolution Plymouth & Virtual Terminal for ATI/NVIDIA cards with proprietary/restricted driver](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3afav_IHziWNYJ%3aidyllictux.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/lucidubuntu-10-04-high-resolution-plymouth-virtual-terminal-for-atinvidia-cards-with-proprietaryrestricted-driver/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=do) (read **Hwoary**'s comment)