# Terminal Buffer Size

Tags: command-line

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04. I perform a lot of work from the terminal and prefer to switch sessions (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, etc.). My desktop is less cluttered without the Terminal windows.

When I switch sessions (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>), the buffer only takes up the top left quarter of my screen. Does anyone know how I can extend the buffer on both the X and Y axis to utilize more of my monitor?

Thanks!

Comment: Read [Persist screen resolution for Server 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/327679/159545). Maybe changing the resolution might help.

Answer (score 1):

Most terminal programs allow multiple tabs on a given window.

```
  hit cntr-shift t  to open up a new tab
```

Go to your preferences to define window geometry

Comment: The OP is not talking about gnome-terminal, etc. I think he/she is talking about the command line mode (no GUI).

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you Scott.  Tabs will allow me to stay on the X11 session.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
screen -h <Number_of_Lines_you_need>
```

example `screen -h 6000`

Comment: Thanks Mitch, screen -h 6000 buffers the entire monitor (I had to install 'screen' first).